Casting RDD to a different type (from float64 to double)
I have a code like below, which uses pyspark.
test_truth_value = RDD.
test_predictor_rdd = RDD.
valuesAndPred = test_truth_value.zip(lasso_model.predict(test_predictor_rdd)).map(lambda x: ((x[0]), (x[1])))
metrics = RegressionMetrics(valuesAndPred)

When i run the code, I get the following error
pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkTypeError: [CANNOT_ACCEPT_OBJECT_IN_TYPE] `DoubleType()` can not accept object `-44604.288415296396` in type `float64`.

This happens with the below portion.
metrics = RegressionMetrics(valuesAndPred)

In general, I would fix the type of RDD by following something like the below link answer.
Pyspark map from RDD of strings to RDD of list of doubles
However...I have three questions now.

What is the difference between float64 and double?
Swift Difference Between Double and Float64
From this link, it seems like the pyspark is differenciating float64 and double?
When I created the previous RDDs, I already casted them into double like below.

double_cast_list = ['price','bed','bath','acre_lot','house_size']
for cast_item in double_cast_list:
    top_zip_df = top_zip_df.withColumn(cast_item, col(cast_item).cast(DoubleType()))

lasso_df = top_zip_df.select('price','bed','bath','acre_lot','house_size')
train_df, test_df = lasso_df.randomSplit(weights = [0.7,0.3], seed = 100)

def scaled_rdd_generation(df):
    rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[0], row[1::]))
    
    # separate the features and the lables from rdd - only need to standardize the features. 
    features_rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: row.features) # this is possible, because the LabeledPoint class has label and feature columns already built in
    scaler = StandardScaler(withMean = True, withStd = True)
    # for the standard scaler, you need to fit the scaler and then transforme the df. 
    # scaler.fit(rdd) -> computes the mean and variance and stores as a model to be used later
    scaler_model =  scaler.fit(features_rdd)
    scaled_feature_rdd = scaler_model.transform(features_rdd)
    # rdd zip method: zips RDD with another one. returns key-value pair. 
    scaled_rdd = rdd.zip(scaled_feature_rdd).map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x[0].label, x[1]))
    return scaled_rdd


model_save_path = r'C:\Users\ra064640\OneDrive - Honda\Desktop\Spark\Real Estate Linear Regression'
train_scaled_rdd = scaled_rdd_generation(train_df)
test_scaled_rdd = scaled_rdd_generation(test_df)
test_predictor_rdd = test_scaled_rdd.map(lambda x: x.features)
test_truth_value = test_scaled_rdd.map(lambda x: x.label)

Where in there is it transforming the double to float64?

How should I fix this? I do not see a function similar to double(x[0]) as suggested by float(x[0]) in the previous link.
Thanks!


First, as mentioned in Spark docs - here's the difference between float and double type:


FloatType: Represents 4-byte single-precision floating point numbers.
DoubleType: Represents 8-byte double-precision floating point numbers.


Second, as you mentioned the error comes here:
valuesAndPred = test_truth_value.zip(lasso_model.predict(test_predictor_rdd)).map(lambda x: ((x[0]), (x[1])))
metrics = RegressionMetrics(valuesAndPred)

More specifically, the issue may have arisen because of this part: lasso_modle.predict(test_predictor_rdd).
Finally, to fix this you may try casting the predictions as well as lasso_model.predict(test_predictor_rdd).map(float).
Modified code:
valuesAndPred = test_truth_value.zip(lasso_model.predict(test_predictor_rdd).map(float)).map(lambda x: ((x[0]), (x[1])))
metrics = RegressionMetrics(valuesAndPred)


thank you. the solution worked. Just 2 questions. From the error output, it seems like Spark is expecting double, as it says doubletype() cannot accept float. So why would casting to float fix this issue? I was expecting to cast to double since spark does see float and double differently. Second, since the input of the RegressionMetrics function is usually some_model.predict(predictor_input). Why would Spark design it in the way that the predictions has to be casted before using RegressionMetrics?

@InkyuKim From what I know, the explicit casting to float before passing data to RegressionMetrics is ensuring that Spark interprets the numerical values correctly as DoubleType - just a prudent step to handle errors due to differences in how Python and Spark handle numerical types (basically the Python float64 and spark's DoubleType are conceptually similar but different in their context - hence the error).

So, casting explicitly to float - in your code's context isn't about changing the data type - instead, it ensures that Python's representation of numerical values (float64) aligns with what Spark expects (DoubleType). I know this might seem counter-intuitive - but that's how it is. For more detailed info - you'll have to dive into the spark internals.
